# Hover Over Link to Effect Another Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

What im trying to do is when I hover over a anchor tag link on the same page, it also needs to affect the corresponding link.

It might be possible in CSS but I think JQuery would handle this better.

Im new to jquery

Heres my code:

```
<script>
$('.js-tooltip').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('js-tooltip-active')
})
</script>
```

Heres my CSS:

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding: 0 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #b71a71;
  box-shadow: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tooltip:hover {
  background: #b1d12d;
}
.tooltip-wrapper {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: -125px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.js-tooltip-active .tooltip-wrapper,
.tooltip:hover .tooltip-wrapper,
.tooltip-wrapper:hover {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
.tooltip-wrapper:after {
  z-index: 11;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -7px;
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-top: 7px solid #333;
}
.tooltip-wrapper:before {
  bottom: -9px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.tooltip-text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 9px;
  z-index: 10;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 18px;
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-shadow: none;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}



<div class="mapbox"><img src="#" style="z-index: 101; border: none" width="672" height="744"  usemap="#Map"/>
<a class="tooltip js-tooltip manmap" href="#" style="top: -315px; left: 270px; border: none; "><span class="tooltip-wrapper" style="z-index: 103; border: none; "><span class="tooltip-text" style="z-index: 103; cursor: pointer; border: none;">View</span></span></a>
<a class="tooltip js-tooltip lonmap" href="#" style="top: -150px; left: 365px;"><span class="tooltip-wrapper" style="z-index: 103;"><span class="tooltip-text" style="z-index: 103; cursor: pointer;">View</span></span></a>
</div>
```

What the code above does is when I hover over the hotspot a small title box appears that the user can click.

```
<div id="col3" class="right">

<h2>Select a location<img src="#" width="21" height="18" alt="icon" /></h2>

<div class="box">
    <h3>Select</h3>
    <ul id="locationList">
        <li class="a"><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the `<li>` link list that I would like to connect to the map.

What I want is to try and replicate the effect of the circle hover but on the links, I don't want to show and hide the circle markers on the map I would just like them to appear when the corresponding link has been hovered over.

Also the Map markers change colour from purple to green am I able to replicate that effect hovering over the links in the sidebar.

So basically when I hover over the circle marker the title tag pops up with the link, that is what I would like the link to do as well so I can hover over link and it will do the same and hovering over the circle and vice-versa.

I don't know if this helps but this is where I got the code for the tooltip/hotspot Heres the link, then I changed the code for it to look circle.

Thanks.

Comment: AJSfiddle demo would be of great assistance but I think you might want to think in terms of `data-attributes` and two separate JQ functions.

Comment: @paulie_D this is where i got it from, ive just customised it to the style i need, and also changed it from stylus to CSS and Jade to HTML. Heres the [link](http://codepen.io/nicholasjohn/pen/xwqlL)

Comment: The demo needs the image as well..show us what you have now.

Comment: @Paulie_D what do you need me to show you. Do you need it in a JSfiddle?

Comment: I need to see what you have so far...I have some ideas but I need to see how they would incorporate into your code.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks so far Paulie_D heres the JSFiddle, [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/JaHe/vPvFc/)

Comment: Answer given, hope it's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok....it took a little doing because my Jquery skills are poor so I'm sure this could be refactored and simplified but here goes.

We have to add an individual attribute to each list item, I use a `data-attribute` which can then be used to select each individual map point which will have it's own ID

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vPvFc/6/)

**Revised HTML**

```
<div id="col5" class="left">

    <h1>Pick A Location</h1>


    <div class="mapbox">       

        <a id="A" class="tooltip js-tooltip" href="#">
            <span class="tooltip-wrapper">
                <span class="tooltip-text">View 1</span>
            </span>
        </a>

        <a id="B" class="tooltip js-tooltip" href="#">
            <span class="tooltip-wrapper" >
                <span class="tooltip-text">View 2</span>
            </span>
        </a>        
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <h3>Select a location</h3>
    <ul id="locationList">
        <li><a data-item="A" href="#">View 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-item="B" href="#">View 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

I just added an `.active' class for the list item links

```
#locationList a.active {
    color:red;
}
```

EDIT- and for the tooltip something similar

```
.tooltip.current {
  background: #b1d12d;
}
```

**Jquery**

I added these two functions

```
$('.tooltip').hover(function() {
     $('a[data-item="'+this.id+'"]').toggleClass('active');
});
```

/* when a tooltip is hovered, find the anchor which has a data-item attribute that matches the ID of the hovered element and toggle the active class */

```
  $('#locationList a').hover(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('item')).toggleClass('js-tooltip-active');
    $('#' + $(this).data('item')).toggleClass('current'); /* EDIT for hover */
});
```

/* when list item link is hovered, find the matching ID toggle the js-tooltip-active class */

Comment: It works but I just have 1 small question. How do I get the circle to change colour when "view 1" link is hovered over. apart from that its quality thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Add a class like `.tooltip.current {background: #b1d12d;}` and then toggle it the same way - Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vPvFc/6/

Comment: A few people in the office are using IE9, the sidebar links are not working, i know why because we are using data-item which is HTML5. also the Circle hotspots are a little bit jumpy, can this be corrected in jquery, or is there nothing that can be done?

Comment: You could use an individual for each anchor link (.item1) and use that instead.

Comment: Sorry for being stupid but will it go in here `$('.tooltip').hover(function() {
     $('a[data-item="'+this.id+'"]').toggleClass('active');
});`

Comment: It will probably take me a whole to figure this out so you might want to post a new question on SO in the nmeantime saying that you need to adapt what you have for IE9 support.

Comment: I've created another question, for IE9 support if you have time to take alook that would be most appreciated. Heres the [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322910/hover-over-link-to-effect-another-link-ie9-support)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need. it is no my code all the credit goes to the author of the link below. Check the link to see the live example.

```
    #one:hover ~ #three,
#six:hover ~ #four,
#seven:hover ~ .box {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
#four {
    margin-left: -35px;
}
#six {
    left: 80px;
    position: relative;
}
.box {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/a3y52/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but think its going to have to be jQuery because it is initialized by jQuery, i've tried your code above but I cannot seem to get it to work.